# Data-Theme not applying to Subpage - JQuery mobile and Phonegap

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to develop in an application, which is based on Phonegap and JQuery Mobile framework.

I have created a Page and Sub Page as separate HTML files.

The body part of the index.html file will look like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1" **data-theme="e"**>
<div data-role="header">App Name</div>
<div data-role="content" class="fit-content"><br/>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"  data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="slide">
<li><a href="page2.html#p2" rel="external">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html#p3" rel="external">Link2</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

The body part of page2.html file will look like:

```
<div data-role="subpage" id="p2" **data-theme="e"**>
<div data-role="header">Places</div>
<div data-role="content" class="fit-content"><br/>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"  data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="slide">
<li><a href="index.html#p1" rel="external">Go Back</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

The data-theme="e" is successfully getting applied to index.html, whereas it is not getting applied to page2.html. Can someone please provide me with the reasons, for this behavior..?

I am using JQuery 1.8.3 and JQuery Mobile 1.2.1 version and I am properly calling the CSS and JS versions **from local storage** in both the HTML files (**ex: /android_asset/www/css**/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css, **ex: /android_asset/www/js**/jquery-1.8.3.js/)

- Also, another question lingering in my mind is, I am unable to call
  the CLICK event for Link1, when I keep the body content of page2.html
  in the same HTML file as index.html, as a SubPage; upon click on Link1, I am not redirected to Page2.html, even though I give **href="#p2"**, **instead of href-"page2.html#p2"**.

Comment: Try rename your subpage to page.

Comment: I am getting an empty screen. The screen blinked for a couple of times, then I got this empty screen.

Comment: The issue should be with data-ajax="false" then...rename subpage to page and data-ajax="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide **data-ajax="false"** in list divider of index.html.  This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. As per [this link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html),

> "Providing **data-ajax="false"** is critical because Ajax pages use the
>   hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use
>   the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be a conflicts."

Also, rename data-role="subpage" to data-role="page". This is the solution to this problem.